# Не срабатывает удаление cookie через AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, cookie

Есть файл `del.php` в этом файле есть такой код:

```
SetCookie("mycookie","",time()-86401, "/");
```

Так вот, если я напрямую обращаюсь к этому файлу, то все хорошо, куки удаляются, а если я делаю AJAX запрос:

```
$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "/ajax/del.php",
   data: "vihod=da",
   success: function(msg){
   }
});
```

То куки не удаляются. В чем причина, может кто знает?

Answer (score 0):

причина в том что вы забываете перезагрузить страницу, ajax удаляет куки на сервере но сама страница при этом новые заголовки не устанавливает.

Comment: После ajax запроса я жму F5, но куки по прежнему не удаляются

Comment: для удаления кук на сервере вроде так надо сделать     
private function destroySession(){
    session_name();
     session_start();
        $_SESSION = [];

        unset($_COOKIE[session_name()]);

        session_destroy();

    }

Comment: Мне надо удалить не все куки, а только вот эти "mycookie", остальные куки меня не интересуют

Comment: тогда вот так private function destroySession(){ session_name("mycookie"); session_start(); $_SESSION = []; unset($_COOKIE[session_name("mycookie")]); session_destroy(); }

Comment: если только значение то просто unset($_COOKIE["mycookie"])

Comment: Попробовал, не срабатывает

Comment: по-моему куки так не удалить т.к. функция SetCookie отправляет заголовки, а браузер ожидает некие данные и не воспринимает их как заголовки. была когда-то такая задача, решил редиректом на страницу удаления кук (как раз с SetCookie) с последующим редиректом.

Comment: впрочем, можно удалять их без аяксов, в $_SESSION куки не хранятся, они хранятся в $_COOKIE и формируются при каждом запросе. т.е. новый запрос будет без куки, которая удалена с помощью js.